# JQ select and passing arguments

Tags: bash, select, filter, arguments, jq

I am trying to passing variables to JQ but the following code is not working as expected:

```
echo '{
   "app": "K8s",
   "version": "1.8",
   "date": "2018-10-10"
}' | jq --arg app 'K8s' -c 'select(.app == [$app]).version'
```

However, following example works:

```
echo '{
   "app": "K8s",
   "version": "1.8",
   "date": "2018-10-10"
}' | jq -r --arg app app 'select(.[$app] == "K8s").version'
```

why the first example is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, `[$app]` is wrong: this expression produces an array. The jq program should be:

```
select(.app == $app).version
```